# Filtering an array based on matching value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to filter an array with all the possible matches. How can i implement please guide me.

```
arr = [{test: 100}, {test: 100A}, {test: 100B}, {test: 100C}, {test: 101}, {test: 101}]
// i want to filter the above array which matches 100.

I have tried.
var arr1 = arr.filter(x => x.test === 100);
console.log(arr1);
it returns only {test: 100} instead i want {test: 100}, {test: 100A}, {test: 100B}, {test: 100C}
```

Comment: `{test: 100A}` is not valid javascript syntax, are you sure this is the array?

Comment: You'll get `SyntaxError` with your current `arr`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your `test` values are actually strings, you can use [`String.startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) to do the filtering:

```js
arr = [
  {test: '100'}, {test: '100A'}, {test: '100B'},
  {test: '100C'}, {test: '101'}, {test: '101'}
];

arr1 = arr.filter(o => o.test.startsWith('100'));
console.log(arr1);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple `ways` you can do this:

You can use `filter` and `includes` function together to see if value test is `100` and other matching strings.

Using [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
let arr = [{test: '100'}, {test: '100A'}, {test: '100B'}, {test: '100C'}, {test: '101'}, {test: '101'}]

var arr1 = arr.filter(str => str.test.includes('100'));

console.log(arr1);
```

You can use filter will `indexOf`

Using [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexof)

```js
let arr = [{test: '100'}, {test: '100A'}, {test: '100B'}, {test: '100C'}, {test: '101'}, {test: '101'}]

var arr1 = arr.filter(str => str.test.indexOf('100') > -1);

console.log(arr1);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var arr1 = arr.filter(x => x.test.includes(100));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `===`, you are checking `exact` value and type.

If you want to filter based on value, first convert the `string` to value using `parseInt` and then compare.

```js
const arr = [{test: '100'}, {test: '100A'}, {test: '100B'}, {test: '100C'}, {test: '101'}, {test: '101'}]

const res = arr.filter(({test}) => parseInt(test) === 100);

console.log(res);
```